# dynamic macro definition problem

Tags: macros

It is likely that the answer to the problem is buried on this site somewhere -- it is my limited understanding of macro expansion which seems to defy my search foo...

I am trying to define macros which I can use like this:

```
\begin{document}

  \AimTaskDef{1}{task 1}
  \AimTaskAdd{1}{task 2}

  \AimTaskDef{2}{task 3}
  \AimTaskAdd{2}{task 4}

  ...
  % later, in some table
  \AimTaskGet{1}

  \AimTaskGet{2}
```

Which should result in output like this

```
\begin{itemize}
 \item task 1
 \item task 2
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}
 \item task 3
 \item task 4
\end{itemize}
```

I have the following macro set in place:

```
 \def\AimTaskDef#1#2{%
   \expandafter\def\csname AimTask#1\endcsname{ \item #2}
 }

 \def\AimTaskAdd#1#2{%
   \expandafter\def\tmp{\expandafter\csname AimTask#1\endcsname}
   \expandafter\def\csname AimTask#1\endcsname{ \tmp \item #2}
 }

 \def\AimTaskGet#1{ \begin{itemize} \csname AimTask#1\endcsname \end{itemize} }
```

I am doing something wrong with the 'tmp' definition/usage, as I see
the following errors:

```
\AimTaskAdd #1#2->\expandafter \def \tmp
                                         {\expandafter \csname AimTask#1\end...
l.28       \AimTaskAdd{1}{task 2}

?
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text>
                \inaccessible
l.28       \AimTaskAdd{1}{task 2}

?
```

and the result contains only the last specified task.  I would
appreciate any insight in what is going on with \tmp.

Many thanks, Andre.

Comment: Pretty sure your problem is here `\expandafter\def\tmp`.  The `\expandafter` skips `\def` and tries to expand `\tmp` which hasn't been defined.  I get an undefined control sequence at that point when copy/pasting your code into a document.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following does what you're after (but requires e-TeX; it can be modified to work without as well):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\AimTaskDef#1#2{%
  \expandafter\def\csname AimTask#1\endcsname{ \item #2}%
}
\def\AimTaskAdd#1#2{%
  \ifcsname AimTask#1\endcsname
    % Check for repeated entries (AM):
    \@expandtwoargs\in@
      {\detokenize{\item #2}}
      {\detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname AimTask#1\endcsname}}%
    \ifin@\else
      \expandafter\g@addto@macro\csname AimTask#1\endcsname{\item #2}%
    \fi      
  \else
    \AimTaskDef{#1}{#2}%
  \fi%
}
\def\AimTaskGet#1{\begin{itemize}\csname AimTask#1\endcsname\end{itemize}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Explicit definition:

\begin{itemize}
 \item task 1
 \item task 2
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}
 \item task 3
 \item task 4
\end{itemize}

\ldots

Macro definition:

\AimTaskAdd{1}{task 1}
\AimTaskAdd{1}{task 2}
\AimTaskDef{2}{task 3}
\AimTaskAdd{2}{task 4}
\AimTaskAdd{2}{task 4} % Repeated (AM)


\AimTaskGet{1}

\AimTaskGet{2}
\end{document}
```

In order to append things to an existing macro, it's sufficient to use `\g@addto@macro{<macro>}{<stuff>}`. Also, I've updated `\AimTaskAdd` to check for the existence of `AimTask#1` and create it if it doesn't exist. That allows you to do

```
\AimTaskAdd{1}{task 1}
\AimTaskAdd{1}{task 2}
```

without being concerned that `AimTask1` exists already (I've also used this in my example as an illustration).

Comment: `\g@addto@macro` -- cool!  Excellent, that is exactly what I was looking for, really :-)

Answer (score 5):

An implementation with `expl3` facilities.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\AimTaskDef}{ m m }{ \andre_task_def:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
\NewDocumentCommand{\AimTaskAdd}{ m m }{ \andre_task_add:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
\NewDocumentCommand{\AimTaskGet}{ m }
 {
  \begin{itemize} \prop_get:Nn \g_andre_tasks_prop { #1 } \end{itemize}
 }

\prop_new:N \g_andre_tasks_prop
\msg_new:nnn { andre } { task-exist }
 {
  Task~#1~already~exists:~I'm~overwriting~it
 }
\msg_new:nnn { andre } { task-not-exist }
 {
  Task~#1~doesn't~exist~yet:~I'm~defining~it
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \andre_task_def:nn #1 #2
 {
  \prop_if_in:NnT \g_andre_tasks_prop { #1 } 
   {
    \msg_warning:nnx { andre } { task-exist } { #1 }
   }
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_andre_tasks_prop { #1 } { \item #2 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \andre_task_add:nn #1 #2
 {
  \prop_if_in:NnTF \g_andre_tasks_prop { #1 }
   {
    \prop_gput:Nnx \g_andre_tasks_prop { #1 }
     {
      \prop_get:Nn \g_andre_tasks_prop { #1 } \exp_not:n { \item #2 }
     }
   }
   {
    \msg_warning:nnx { andre } { task-not-exist } { #1 }
    \prop_gput:Nnn \g_andre_tasks_prop { #1 } { \item #2 }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\AimTaskDef{1}{task 1}
\AimTaskAdd{1}{task 2}

\AimTaskDef{2}{task 3}
\AimTaskAdd{2}{task 4}

\AimTaskGet{1}

\AimTaskGet{2}

\AimTaskDef{1}{task 1}
\AimTaskAdd{3}{task !}
\end{document}
```

The macros warn if `\AimTaskDef` is used with an already defined task and, in this case, overwrite it (this could be changed); they also warn if `\AimTaskAdd` is used on a not yet defined task (and define it).

A possibly more efficient version (thanks to Bruno Le Floch):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\AimTaskDef}{ m m }{ \andre_task_def:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
\NewDocumentCommand{\AimTaskAdd}{ m m }{ \andre_task_add:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
\NewDocumentCommand{\AimTaskGet}{ m }
 {
  \begin{itemize} \prop_get:Nn \g_andre_tasks_prop { #1 } \end{itemize}
 }

% Variables    
\prop_new:N \g_andre_tasks_prop
\tl_new:N \l_andre_temp_tl

% Messages
\msg_new:nnn { andre } { task-exists }
 {
  Task~#1~already~exists:~I'm~overwriting~it
 }
\msg_new:nnn { andre } { task-exists-not }
 {
  Task~#1~doesn't~exist~yet:~I'm~defining~it
 }

% Functions
\cs_new_protected:Npn \andre_task_def:nn #1 #2
 {
  \prop_if_in:NnT \g_andre_tasks_prop { #1 } 
   {
    \msg_warning:nnx { andre } { task-exists } { #1 }
   }
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_andre_tasks_prop { #1 } { \item #2 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \andre_task_add:nn #1 #2
 {
  \prop_get:NnNTF \g_andre_tasks_prop { #1 } \l_andre_temp_tl
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_andre_temp_tl { \item #2 }
    \prop_gput:NnV \g_andre_tasks_prop { #1 } \l_tmpa_tl
   }
   {
    \msg_warning:nnx { andre } { task-exists-not } { #1 }
    \prop_gput:Nnn \g_andre_tasks_prop { #1 } { \item #2 }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\AimTaskDef{1}{task 1}
\AimTaskAdd{1}{task 2}

\AimTaskDef{2}{task 3}
\AimTaskAdd{2}{task 4}

\AimTaskGet{1}

\AimTaskGet{2}

\AimTaskDef{1}{task 1}
\AimTaskAdd{3}{task !}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would personally use `\prop_get:NnNTF` in `\andre_task_add:nn` to retrieve the old value in a temporary variable and test `if_in` at the same time.  It may still be marked as an experimental function in the version on CTAN, but it is now not experimental anymore (upload to CTAN in a few days).  The only drawback of using `\prop_get:NnNTF` is that you will need an auxiliary token list variable.